# Can we "warm start" a MILP optimization with MIPCL with an initial feasible solution?

Tags: python, linear-programming, solver, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have spent sometime scanning through the available documentation of MIPCL and reading the forum posts that seemed to mention close issues, but I still don't have an answer :

**As with many other MILP solvers (Gurobi, CPLEX, CBC...), can we provide MIPCL with an existing feasible solution so that it starts the optimization from it ?**

I started to doubt the functionality exists when I learned that, even though the Pulp interface with MIPCL exists, MIPCL is not in the list of solvers for which Pulp allows this type of "warm start". Then again, the fact that it is not in Pulp does not mean it is not possible through the native APIs, but I did not find anything on the topic.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

PuLP can only provide a warm start if the solver itself provides a warm start option. Thus, you should first look in the MIPCL documentation to see if that is functionality provided by MIPCL (http://www.mipcl-cpp.appspot.com/). Unfortunately, the site has been down for some time.

PuLP uses the command line interface for MIPCL and I suspect that, at least in this interface, it does not provide a "warm start" option. The arguments for the command line are the following:

```
C:\Users\pchtsp>mps_mipcl
Usage: mps_pMIPCL/mps_MIPCL [options] filename.mps[.gz]
   -solfile {file name for storing solution}   -threads {number of thread}
   -time {time in seconds}
   -gap {duality gap in percents}
   -objBound {lover or upper bound on the objective}
   -LPmethod {PRIME, DUAL}
   -pricingRule {DANCIG,STEEPEST,PARTIAL}
   -sepRule {DANCIG,STEEPEST,PARTIAL}
   -preprocess {0,1}
   -cuts l,h (l,h in {-1,0,1,...} are #cuts for, resp., low and high nodes)
   -click {cut pattern}
   -knapsack {cut pattern}
   -gomory {cut pattern}
   -mod2 {cut pattern}
   -mir {cut pattern}
           file_name
----------------------------------------------------------------
cut pattern depth1,mod1,depth2,mod2  where depth1,depth2 in {-1,0,1,2,...
```

It does not mean that MIPCL doesn't provide a "warm start" option via some other interface (e.g., the python interface).

Comment: Thanks ! I totally agree, and thanks for the concrete example on PuLP. I'm hoping someone managed to be more efficient than me at parsing the direct MIPCL APIs documentation pages to find whether or not it is possible, I'll keep on searching on my hand and update my post if I stumble across an answer